# What happens when you don't check your data and ask questions first... should I delete this?

Tags: etherscan

Take look at my contract transaction history:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe42d26e4a66e9562b40bde44e4ceff706fd67d20

**I verified my contract so you can see everything using etherscan interface!!**

You will notice I set sell/buy price in this transaction (I called it multiple times).
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd03f3b07cb2ba66d3b9661ce584ff11873c517a830b0dda456863415c7954116

In this transaction I set buy price to 100.
You can read that it is indeed so:
    https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe42d26e4a66e9562b40bde44e4ceff706fd67d20#readContract

In these transactions I bought tokens for 0.01 ether

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x41958bf1de73ece017be737eab94db1040d2a5614048011c95027be4e01e4782
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf57bbbf3ee155a9992c229c473d328e0e7ccbe8f3fd14325d474e22c450a7ec0

and some others.

What is evident from log is that I received 0.0001 tokens in return as if msg.value was 0.01 and not 10000000000000000 wei.
From official docs [msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg.value#special-variables-and-functions)

**Why is result interpreted as if msg.value is in ether and not wei?**

I am testing a contract on a Ropsten network using geth 1.8.8 with command line:

```
geth --testnet --datadir="x:\\a\\b\\GethWithRopsten\\"
```

In order to connect to geth I use web3js version 1, beta 34 running from node.js:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new web3.providers.IpcProvider('\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc',net));
```

Compiler I use is solc 4.24 release.

Relevant code is (this code is almost all taken from example ERC20 token):

```
function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return a / b;
}

function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
    buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
}

function buy() payable onlyIfEnabled public {
    uint256 amount = msg.value.div(buyPrice);   
    _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);   
}
```

and

```
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal returns (bool){
   require (_to != 0x0);
   require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
   require (balanceOf[_to].add(_value) > balanceOf[_to]);
   require(!frozenAccount[_from]);
   require(!frozenAccount[_to]);
   balanceOf[_from] = balanceOf[_from].sub(_value);
   balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
   emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
   return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please split your question in multiple questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble here is that I was not reading values correctly. Tokens are displayed with their decimal places as opposed to displaying values that hold them that are integers.